# Efficient algorithm for counting of duplicate elements in an array which doesn't fit into RAM

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, bigdata

I think that the subject describes the question to the full extent. I need to count repetitions of elements in an array which I can not fully load into computer memory. Array can have a size of 50Gb and even greater. In my certain task the elements of this array are strings which has the length not more than 256 characters encoded in UTF-8 (512 bytes in total). The number of strings is ~100 million. For example if I have the following array on the input (strings are shortened for the sake of brevity):

```
VERY NICE ELEMENT_1
VERY NICE ELEMENT_1
VERY NICE ELEMENT_2
VERY NICE ELEMENT_2
NOT SO GOOD ELEMENT
NOT SO GOOD ELEMENT
BAD ELEMENT
BAD ELEMENT
BAD ELEMENT
PERFECT FIFTH ELEMENT
```

The algorithm should output the following (maybe not exactly in that order):

```
VERY NICE ELEMENT_1 2
VERY NICE ELEMENT_2 2
NOT SO GOOD ELEMENT 2
BAD ELEMENT 3
PERFECT FIFTH ELEMENT 1
```

In other words I need to do what `SELECT COUNT(*) GROUP BY` does.

I guess that the algorithm should perform counting in multiple stages by dividing the elements into some groups which are fit into RAM normally. Then it should reduce that groups into one single group. But how can it do this? How can it merge that groups efficiently?

Hard disk has potentinally unlimitted capacity. The programming language doesn't matter. I need to know just an abstract algorithm. I had an experience with analogous task where I need to sort that kind of array. There I did the same thing with dividing all the elements into partitions and then merging them into one single file. But in this case I don't know how to do "the merging part".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why not to use a database?  It already has all the features you are looking for effectively implemented,

Comment: Sorting the file is an option. After that, just process the file sequentially and count equal items, which will be together.

Comment: Database. Disable transactions and write logging for more speed if you don't need durability. And then you do `SELECT COUNT(*) GROUP BY` just like you said.

Comment: Do you need exact accurate result? Or, is close approximation acceptable?

Comment: @Arun Are there any approximate algorithms? I need the exact result but what will your suggestions be in other case?

Comment: Database is the option but let's imagine that we want to implement our own database with blackjack and ... for a while.

@cecilio-pardo, yes, it sounds like quite an interesting idea. Can you post it as an answer to my question?

Comment: An approximate version could just test a part of the file, assuming there are not many possible strings. If you process 10% of the file, just multiply your numbers by 10.

Comment: @Dobby007: If approximation is okay, then we can **hash** the string into a number and put them in an unordered_set<int64>. At the the end, the size of the unordered_set would be the count. I am assuming that the unique count would fit into RAM though.

Comment: @Arun, thank you. I understood your idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pseudocode

**1st stage : partial processing + partitioning**

Let **M** be the string-to-occurrence map

1. While the end of the input file was not reached do
2. Read next string **s** from the file
3. If **s** is not in **M**, let **M**[**s**] = 0
4. **M**[**s**] += 1
5. If the size of **M** exceeds some limit, sort **M** by key, write it into a new temporary file **F**<sub>**i**</sub>, and reset **M**
6. End of loop
7. Flush **M** just like on step 5

---

**2nd stage : merging**

Input: Files {**F**<sub>**i**</sub>} of the format 'key value' on every line (sorted by key)

Let **P** be a *priority queue* of triplets {`K V F`} where sorting is performed only by the first element of the triplet, i.e. by `K`

1. For each file **f** from {**F**<sub>**i**</sub>} read the first line '`key value`' from **f** and push {`key value` **f** } into **P**
2. Let current_key='', current_value=0
3. While **P** is not empty
4. Pop {`key1 value1` **f** } from **P**
5. If end of **f** has not been reached, read the next line '`key2 value2`' from **f** and push {`key2 value2` **f**} back into **P**, otherwise close and delete **f**
6. If `current_key == key1` then `current_value += value1`, else output `current_key current_value`,
   and set `current_key=key1`, `current_value=value1`
7. End of loop
8. Output `current_key current_value`

---

## Python implementation

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import heapq
import os
import tempfile

class Partitions(list):
    def __init__(self, stream, max_lines_per_partition, tmpdir):
        self.tmpdir=tmpdir
        m = {}
        for line in stream:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            if not line in m:
                if len(m) == max_lines_per_partition:
                    self.save(m)
                    m.clear()
                m[line] = 0
            m[line] += 1

        if len(m) > 0:
            self.save(m)
        del m

    def save(self, m):
        i = len(self)
        new_partition_fname = '{}/part{}'.format(self.tmpdir, i)
        self.append(new_partition_fname)
        f = open(new_partition_fname, 'w')
        for key in sorted(m.keys()):
            f.write('{} {}\n'.format(key, m[key]))
        f.close()


class PartitionEntryIterator:
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname
        self.f = open(fname, 'r')
        self.next()

    def next(self):
        line = self.f.readline()
        if len(line) != 0:
            self.key, self.count = line.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
            self.count = int(self.count.rstrip('\n'))
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __del__(self):
        self.f.close()

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.key < other.key

def count_distinct_lines(lines, max_lines_per_partition):
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
        h = []
        for fname in Partitions(lines, max_lines_per_partition, tmpdir):
            x = PartitionEntryIterator(fname)
            heapq.heappush(h, x)

        key = h[0].key
        count = 0
        while not len(h) == 0:
            x = heapq.heappop(h)
            if key == x.key:
                count += x.count
            else:
                yield (key, count)
                key, count = x.key, x.count
            if x.next():
                heapq.heappush(h, x)

        yield (key, count)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print('Usage:\n\t' + sys.argv[0] + ' <max-lines-per-partition>')
        exit(1)

    for key, count in count_distinct_lines(sys.stdin, int(sys.argv[1])):
        print(key, count, sep=': ')
```

Comment: I think your idea is the best by now. You don't need to sort the whole file and then process it after all. You just need its' sorted partitions that were received based on the raw data.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the file, and then process it sequentially and count equal items, which will be together. You can then output result records on the fly, as soon as one item differs from the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

I would just split the file into multiple files according to hash code of each line. Make 1000x 50MB file from 1x 50GB file. Then process each file separately, it would fit into memory without problems.

```
protected static string[] Partition(string inputFileName, string outPath, int partitions)
{
    string[] fileNames = Enumerable.Range(0, partitions)
        .Select(i => Path.Combine(outPath, "part" + i))
        .ToArray();

    StreamWriter[] writers = fileNames
        .Select(fn => new StreamWriter(fn))
        .ToArray();

    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(inputFileName);
    string line;
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        int partition = Math.Abs(line.GetHashCode() % partitions);
        writers[partition].WriteLine(line);
    }
    file.Close();

    writers.AsParallel().ForAll(c => c.Close());

    return fileNames;
}

protected static void CountFile(string inputFileName, StreamWriter writer)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(inputFileName);
    string line;
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        int count;
        if (dict.TryGetValue(line, out count))
        {
            dict[line] = count + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            dict.Add(line, 1);
        }
    }
    file.Close();

    foreach (var kv in dict)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(kv.Key + ": " + kv.Value);
    }
}

protected static void CountFiles(string[] fileNames, string outFile)
{
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outFile);
    foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
    {
        CountFile(fileName, writer);
    }
    writer.Close();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fileNames = Partition("./data/random2g.txt", "./data/out", 211);           
    CountFiles(fileNames, "./data/random2g.out");
}
```

**Benchmark**

I decided to try to compare the sorting approach (by Leon) and the hashing. Sorting is quite a lot of work if You do not really need it. I made file with 2 billion numbers. The distribution `(long)Math.Exp(rnd.NextDouble() * 30)` produces all lengths of numbers (up to 14) with the same probability. This distribution produces many unique values, but at the same time also values that repeat many times. Even probability of characters vary. It is not that bad for artificial data.

```
File size: 16,8GiB
Number of lines: 2G (=2000000000)
Number of distinct lines: 576M
Line occurences: 1..46M, average: 3,5
Line length: 1..14, average: 7
Used characters: '0', '1',...,'9'
Character frequency: 8,8%..13%, average: 10%
Disc: SSD
```

**Sorting results**

```
10M lines in partition
10M distinct lines in partition
114 partitions
Partition size: 131MiB
Sum of partitions size: 14,6GiB
Partitioning time: 105min
Merging time: 180min
Total time: 285min (=4hod 45min)
```

This approach saves space as the partitions contain partially merged data.

**Hashing results**

```
7M..54M lines in partition, average: 9,5M
2723766..2732318 distinct lines in partition, average: 2,73M
211 partitions
Partition size 73MiB..207MiB, average: 81MiB
Sum of partitions size: 16,8GiB
Partitioning time: 6min
Merging time: 15min
Total time: 21min
```

While size of each partition vary, number of distinct lines is almost the same in all partitions. It means the hash fuction works as expected. And memory necessary for processing each partition is the same. But it is true that it is not guaranteed, so if high reliability is necessary, some fallback strategy has to be added for those cases (rehashing the file into yet smaller, switching to sorting for that file etc.). Chances are, it would never be really used, so from performace perspective it is not a problem.

Hashing beats sorting by factor more than 10, on the other hand some of that may originate in inefficienty of the python itself.

Comment: You told about how to divide this big file into small ones. But how would you process those small files and receive the final result (i.e. the file with repititions for each unique line)?

Comment: @Dobby007 While all accurences of one string has to end in the same file it is trivial. But I would add it for completeness.

Comment: Now I understood you. But what if all strings (or the most of them) would fall into one bucket because they would have the same remainder staying different at the same time?

Comment: @Dobby007 All hashing algorithms rely on the fact, that hashing fuction is reasonably good. If most of different strings end in the same bucket, You need better hashing function if You want to use this approach.

Comment: I agree with you. Good hashing function gives us evenly distibuted hashes for different input strings. Hash is good while it falls into integer range (0 - 2 147 ... ...) but when we calculate the remainder (i.e. hash % 100) we reduce its' hash distribution strength range. Our strings will fall into one of 100 files and the odds that many different string will be written into the same file are higher in this case.

Comment: @Dobby007 Remainder would have weaker selectability (more collisions per bucket), but more evenly distributed items across buckets. For desired purpose only even distribution is needed, nothing more. It is the reason why associative arrays based on hashing use this approach. For curiosity I added some benchmarks.

Comment: You did a great job by comparring these algorithms. But I think it is somewhat dishonest to compare applications written for different platforms. And the second point is that the algorithm written in Python can be optimized a bit by removing call to `sorted` function and using different data structure for storing a map (e.g. red-black tree but with hash table "wrapping" it). But it is really strange that your algorithm gives so big improvements in perfomance even regarding this factor... Of course, in your case no merging of different partitions done at all. Maybe that's the answer...

Comment: @Dobby007 You are right about the platforms, generally. But in this case, I can sort 10M unique strings of this type in 50sec in C#, it means 95min for 114 partitions. Seems on par with the python. If You can remove sorting from that algorithm it would be interesting to see.

Answer (score 0):

Go through a file and put the line index into files by the first letter.

i.e

a 3,45,23...
b 112,34,546...

then you can process these in paralell, as you only need to check each one agains the others per file.

At least that would be my first idea.

Obviously this is the best if the words are mostly random and not everything starts with the same letter, or worst case every word is the same.

Comment: Could you please explain your idea a bit better? What do I need to do with that created index file (the file with every first letter that is met and its' corresponded line numbers)?

Comment: You only need to compare each words with each other in each file. This is easier because this means you dont need to compare each words with ALL the other words. This in theory also could run in paralell because you can have read access to a file in paralell. So you have the line numbers, now you can just read those lines from the big file and do the comparison. If you're efficient you have only 2 times the number of files (in case of English thats 2*26) in memory i.e. 46 words at once.

Answer (score 0):

Use hadoop framework and perform map reduce on your input strings.